# Plot a Dataframe on a basic R chart

Tags: r, dataframe, charts

I think it's a basic question but I didn't saw any answers on SO that solves this.

So, I would like to put each line of this dataframe on a chart, with respective column and row names on x and y axis.

```
> indicador.transposta
                        31-12-2017.pdf     31-12-2018.pdf      31-12-2019.pdf
Liq..Imed.           0.260650162167045  0.278000595266861   0.100940099971038
Liq..Corr.            1.20707183817692   1.07611507200346   0.775547123687795
Liq..Seca             1.01127035774033   0.87978786315216   0.616295652990034
Liq..Geral            1.38911863440832   1.20904526839338    1.22121514777491
Endividamento        0.719880919620619  0.827098890456626   0.818856531399918
Retorno.s..Invest. -0.0281507369406506 -0.110425824989136 0.00682789312217763
Retorno.s..PL       -0.100495606734552 -0.638664640618945   0.037693289053948
Margem.Líquida     -0.0440458341645613 -0.181853784203517  0.0103531380484155
```

The structure is:

```
> str(indicador.transposta)
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ 31-12-2017.pdf: chr  "0.260650162167045" "1.20707183817692" "1.01127035774033" "1.38911863440832" ...
 $ 31-12-2018.pdf: chr  "0.278000595266861" "1.07611507200346" "0.87978786315216" "1.20904526839338" ...
 $ 31-12-2019.pdf: chr  "0.100940099971038" "0.775547123687795" "0.616295652990034" "1.22121514777491" ...
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Base R:

```r
plot(NA, type = "n", xlim = c(1, nrow(dat)), xlab = "", ylim = range(unlist(dat)), ylab = "")
for (y in dat) lines(y)
```

[image: simple base plot]

But dealing with different lines and then optionally coloring and such, it might be easier in the long run to shift to `ggplot2`. That graphic engine prefers its data in a "long" format, so we'll use `tidyr::pivot_longer` to reshape it:

```r
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
library(ggplot2)
pivot_longer(dat, -x)
# # A tibble: 24 x 3
#        x name            value
#  * <int> <chr>           <dbl>
#  1     1 X31.12.2017.pdf 0.261
#  2     1 X31.12.2018.pdf 0.278
#  3     1 X31.12.2019.pdf 0.101
#  4     2 X31.12.2017.pdf 1.21 
#  5     2 X31.12.2018.pdf 1.08 
#  6     2 X31.12.2019.pdf 0.776
#  7     3 X31.12.2017.pdf 1.01 
#  8     3 X31.12.2018.pdf 0.880
#  9     3 X31.12.2019.pdf 0.616
# 10     4 X31.12.2017.pdf 1.39 
# # ... with 14 more rows

ggplot(pivot_longer(dat, -x), aes(x, value, color = name, group = name)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: simple ggplot2]